# Show that a product lies in $(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$, where $d\in\mathbb{Q}$ but $d\notin\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Let $a,b,c$ be distinct rational numbers.

Assume the following facts:

- $(a-\sqrt{d})(b-\sqrt{d})(c-\sqrt{d})\in(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)^*)^2$ (group of nonzero squares)
- $(a+\sqrt{d})(b+\sqrt{d})(c+\sqrt{d})\in(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)^*)^2$
- $(a^2-d)(b-a)(c-a)(a-\sqrt{d})(b-\sqrt{d})(c-\sqrt{d})(a+\sqrt{d})(b+\sqrt{d})(c+\sqrt{d})\in(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$

My Question:

> Is this information enough to conclude that $(a^2-d)(b-a)(c-a)$ also lies in $(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$?
>   It certainly lies in $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)^*)^2$.

Any help/hints would be appreciated! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few hints to help you along the way: consider the 'conjugation' operation $\overline{a+b\sqrt{d}}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{d}$. Then since your conditions imply that there exist $p,q$ such that $(a+\sqrt{d})(b+\sqrt{d})(c+\sqrt{d}) = (p+q\sqrt{d})^2$, you can apply conjugation to both sides of this (why?) to get that $(a-\sqrt{d})(b-\sqrt{d})(c-\sqrt{d})=(p-q\sqrt{d})^2$. Now can you see how to continue from here?

Comment: So we can apply conjugation to both sides since it's a field automorphism right? I guess now $(a-\sqrt{d})(b-\sqrt{d})(c-\sqrt{d})(a+\sqrt{d})(b+\sqrt{d})(c+\sqrt{d}) = (p^2-dq^2)^2$, which is a non zero rational square. So therefore the other term has to be aswell!

Comment: @Tobi That's the basic why, yep! And you know it's a field because $d$ isn't a square so there can't be zero divisors. (You can also just do the computation by hand in this case, since it's so straightforward; just show that $(\overline{a})\cdot(\overline{b}) = \overline{(a\cdot b)}$ by multiplying out.)